# Getting error TypeError: (0 , (_jestUtil || _load_jestUtil(...)).validateCLIOptions) is not a function when running jest

Tags: jestjs

Trying to pin down the source of this error when running jest:

```
TypeError: (0 , (_jestUtil || _load_jestUtil(...)).validateCLIOptions) is not a function
```

My directory structure:

```
root
-test
--spec-files
---*.js
```

Dev dependencies in my package:

```
"devDependencies": {
"babel-eslint": "6.1.2",
"babel-jest": "22.1.0",
"chai": "3.5.0",
"chai-as-promised": "5.3.0",
"eslint": "2.13.1",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "6.2.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "4.3.0",
"jest": "22.1.4",
"jest-cli": "22.1.4",
"jest-runner-eslint": "0.4.0",
"nodemon": "1.12.1",
"nyc": "11.2.1",
"sinon": "2.4.1",
"snyk": "1.69.10",
"spec-xunit-file": "0.0.1-3",
"supertest": "1.2.0",
"supertest-as-promised": "3.2.0",
"xunit-file": "0.0.9"
}
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
estPathIgnorePatterns: [
'<rootDir>/bower_components/',
'<rootDir>/node_modules/',
'<rootDir>/gulp-tasks/',
],
testMatch: ['<rootDir>/test/spec-files/*.js'],
globalSetup: '<rootDir>/test/setup.js',
};
```

Running:

```
./node_modules/.bin/jest --testPathPattern=test/spec-files/.*\\.js$
```

Ive only noticed one issue opened related to this type of bug: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5740

The cause appears to be having an invalid testPathPattern, however that doesnt seem to be the case for me.

Comment: Not exactly the same but I got a similar error and had to `rm -rf node_modules` and then reinstall with `yarn install`. Wasn't an issue after that. Not sure why but you can try that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating jest and jest-cli to the following fixed the issue:

```
"jest": "22.4.4",
"jest-cli": "22.4.4",
```

Comment: Getting the error with `    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "jest-cli": "^26.4.2",`